# MDX join foreign key

Tags: join, ssas, mdx, olap

My problem is how to join on `table1.id = table2.foreign_key` in `MDX`.

I have two dimension: Samples, Patients. and Samples connected sample fact table and Patients connected to patient fact table.
 now I need to get table, it's column is fields from these two tables.

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,CrossJoin
  (
    Union
    (
      Union
      (
        [Sample.patient result info].[data collection].MEMBERS
       ,[Sample.patient result info].[result].MEMBERS
      )
     ,[Sample.patient result info].[code lab].MEMBERS
    )
   ,[Patient.patient sample info].[NID].MEMBERS
  ) ON 1
FROM [EIDCube].
```

So CrossJoin don't need any interaction between tables. What should I do if I need to join like this ?

Comment: have a look on MSDN - maybe you need to add other relationships to your cube: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175669.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In terms of syntax you have a `.` at the very end of your script - this is not valid `mdx`. Standard way of finishing a script is with a semi-colon `;`.

You can simplify the nested `UNION`s by simply having one set, using the notation `{...}` with all the members in it.

Modern cross-join is signified using the `*` operator.

Taking the above into account we now have this:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,
    {
      //<<creates the set
      [Sample.patient result info].[data collection].MEMBERS
     ,[Sample.patient result info].[result].MEMBERS
     ,[Sample.patient result info].[code lab].MEMBERS
    }
  * 
    //<<CrossJoin
    [Patient.patient sample info].[NID].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
//<<finish with a semi-colon
```

You mentioned a fact table - which would seem to imply that you would like to view a measure from the table. So why not include the measure on axis 0:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[SomeMeasureFromFact]} ON 0 //<<replace with actual measure
 ,
    {
      [Sample.patient result info].[data collection].MEMBERS
     ,[Sample.patient result info].[result].MEMBERS
     ,[Sample.patient result info].[code lab].MEMBERS
    }
  * 
    [Patient.patient sample info].[NID].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
```

Now what might happen with the above is that you get lots of rows returning that are empty so apply the `NON EMPTY` key words to the axes:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[SomeMeasureFromFact]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      {
        [Sample.patient result info].[data collection].MEMBERS
       ,[Sample.patient result info].[result].MEMBERS
       ,[Sample.patient result info].[code lab].MEMBERS
      }
    * 
      [Patient.patient sample info].[NID].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
```

If you really do not want any measure `ON 0` then you can use the `NONEMPTY` function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145988.aspx) like so:

```
SELECT 
 {} ON 0
 ,
   NONEMPTY(
      {            
        [Sample.patient result info].[data collection].MEMBERS
       ,[Sample.patient result info].[result].MEMBERS
       ,[Sample.patient result info].[code lab].MEMBERS
      }
    * 
      [Patient.patient sample info].[NID].MEMBERS
   ,[Measures].[SomeMeasureFromFact]
   )
 ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
```

Comment: yes, you're right.. but my question is how to join two dimension just like mysql: select a.name, b.value from tablea a join tableb b on a.id = b.a_id.  So if you use crossjoin, this is join '*', but it isn't linked such as 'mysql a.id = b.a_id', there is some unused data

Comment: @AngelaTian in some of the scripts I have provided I use a measure from the Measures dimension - that way only linked information will be returned: "linked" via the measure. In `mdx` if you just cross join two unrelated dimensions then you get every member against every member - so you need to include a measure to just look at the members that are linked. Please add some information, or a screen-print, to your original question so we can see the desired result table that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help. About the dimension, there's  patient dimension, patient sample info hierarchy , connected patient table(primary key is id), there's many level in hierarchy, such as NID. and another dimension is Sample, patient result info hierarchy, connected sample table(foreign key is patient_id), there's many level in hierarchy, such as result, code lab and so on.   So if I want to use measure ,how to linked ?I don't know how to implement this measure.

Answer (score 0):

> **LinkMember** - Returns the member equivalent to a specified member in a
>   specified hierarchy.
>
> **Syntax** - LinkMember(Member_Expression, Hierarchy_Expression)

Courtest [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146058.aspx)

This is closest to an SQL `JOIN` in MDX.

Say you want the member in `Patient` dimension which has the same key value as the one below -

```
[Samples].[PatientID].&[1001]
```

You need to use something like

```
LinkMember ([Samples].[PatientID].&[1001], [Patient].[PatientID])
```

Once you have the member from the `[Patient].[PatientID]` hierarchy, you can go about playing around to get the measure value.

Note that this function works one member at a time. You cannot pass sets into it.

Hope it helps.

Edit for @whytheq

```
SELECT   LinkMember ([Date].[Date].[July 1, 2002], [Date].[Calendar]) ON 0,
[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

The above script will fetch you the *Reseller Sales Amount* for the member in `[Date].[Calendar]`hierarchy which has the same key value as `[Date].[Date].[July 1, 2002]`.

It is almost on the lines of an SQL JOIN wherein we could join on this key.

There are a lot of limitations but to me it solves the purpose.

Take for instance a situation where there is a measure `[Measures].[M]`out of a fact table F1. There is another hierarchy `D1.H1` . Let's say the requirement is to fetch the value of measure for the member D1.H1.&[SomeValue], BUT, there is no mapping between D1 and F1, but the `Attributes at each level have the same key cardinality and data type`.

We can then leverage this function and use as below -

```
SELECT LinkMember(D1.H1.&[SomeValue], F1.H2) ON 1,
[Measures].m on 0
FROM [SomeCube]
```

Comment: Hi Sourav - I'm sorry but I disagree with your statement `This is closest to an SQL JOIN in MDX`: if you really believe this then please provide a working example of a script that uses this function and is anything like a `sql` join.

Comment: With pleasure amigo! Have edited my code. Let me know if this seems wrong.

Comment: ...no I think this function is more like this `sql` : .... `...WHERE someKey = "101" ` returning *1* row. So more just like `=`. If it returned two sets of data joined together via 1 or several criteria, then we would have some sort of similarity.

Comment: A SQL join too is `=` at a very low level just like the MDX script. If in MDX you want to include the sets, then you would have to maybe create a named set wherein you pass `.CURRENTMEMBER`  instead of exactly `101`. That way dynamically you have the corresponding member from the other hierarchy. This member can then be aggregated with the measure to get the value.

Comment: named sets are not context aware so why would you use `.CURRENTMEMBER` ? Anyway I happy to agree to disagree on this one Sourav - I think this user needs to look beyond `LinkMember` for their answer. Also I think they need something other than my attempt aswell. I think some extra dev is required in their cube - or maybe it is just their general understanding of what `mdx` does.

Comment: MY bad. A named set containing the `GENERATE` function. SQL JOIN has got nothing to do with relationships, but when you talk about foreign keys, relationships comes into picture.So even I am not clear if this would work! My solution is there hanging, still waiting to be tested. Let her come back. To digress a bit, where are you located on the globe? You always seem online ! :))